# Change background-color of bootstrap's pagination

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to change the background-color of pagination with `!import`

static/css/custom_css.css

```
.pagination>li.active>a {
  background-color: orange !important;
}
```

The source code:

```
<nav aria-label="...">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="disabled"><a href="#" aria-label="Previous"><span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span></a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">1 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    ...
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I have import it on the top

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'simplemde/debug/simplemde.css' %}" />
```

I tested multiple colors, but it did not correspond

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its working fine but you need to add this `simplemde.css` after call `bootstrap.css` like below

```css
.pagination>li.active>a {
  background-color: orange !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'simplemde/debug/simplemde.css' %}" />
 
<nav aria-label="...">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="disabled"><a href="#" aria-label="Previous"><span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span></a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">1 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    ...
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: thank you, I am shy to ask could you please introduce an CSS book.

Comment: I think no need of book you can improve and learn CSS from https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

Check which version of bootstrap you are including. Latest version will have active class added to a tag. If so rewrite like `.pagination>li>a.active`